Laravel replaces the connection parameter with the default one
I have a model with a connection parameter to a different database.
class User extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'main_database';
}

When I save the model the connection is returning to default application connection which is named "mysql".
It only happens if one of model values is changed.
 $user = User::find(1);
 $user->surname = 'changed surname';
 $user->save();
    
 dd($user->getConnectionName()); 

Is it a laravel bug?

This question is similar to: change database connection in laravel model. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Check the answer and comment since there are 2 ways stated.

There is nothing in your code that shows you changed the connection.

Maybe there isn't but connection changes

It's necessary to refresh the $user variable.

$user->refresh();

$user = User::find(1);
$user->surname = 'changed surname';
$user->save();

$user->refresh();
    
dd($user->getConnectionName()); 


Unfortunatelly it is not possible because model has default connection at this point

Never mind. I had this in Trackable trait and that was a problem.
public function history()
{
    return $this->setConnection('mysql')->morphToMany(AdmUser::class, 'trackable')->withPivot(['before', 'after'])->withTimestamps();
}

